# Biased Coin Flips

Tags: probability

An experiment consists of tossing three biased coins simultaneously and writing down the outcomes observed. The probabilities of the two outcomes are as follows:
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
P(\text{heads}) &=& \frac{2}{3} \\
P(\text{tails}) &=& \frac{1}{3}
\end{eqnarray}
$$

With these probabilities, what is:

a) the sample space?

b) the probability of an even number of heads?

c) the probability that at least one coin shows heads?

I know that answer $a$ is the sample space $s$ for the eight total outcomes, but I'm really stuck on $b$ and $c$.

Comment: whats a sample space

Comment: A sample space is the set of all possible outcomes of an experiment. It can be denoted as S and is sometimes called the 'Universal Set'.

Comment: What do you mean by even number of heads? You mean what is the possibility of having 1,2,3 heads?

Comment: By even number of heads I mean that of the three coins flipped, an even number of them (in this case two) of them will turn out to be heads.

Answer (score 1):

b)This is $0$ or $2$ heads:
i.e $$P(0_{heads}) + P(2_{heads})$$
$$(\frac{1}{3})^3+(\frac{2}{3} *\frac{2}{3}* \frac{1}{3}) + (\frac{2}{3} *\frac{1}{3}* \frac{2}{3})+(\frac{1}{3} *\frac{2}{3}* \frac{2}{3}) $$
$$\frac{1}{27}+\frac{4}{27}+\frac{4}{27}+\frac{4}{27}$$
$$\frac{13}{27}$$

c)This can be $1,2$ or $3$ coins showing heads
$$P(1_{head})+P(2_{heads})+P(3_{heads})$$
$$(\frac{2}{3}*\frac{1}{3}*\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}*\frac{2}{3}*\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}*\frac{1}{3}*\frac{2}{3})+(\frac{12}{27}) + (\frac{2}{3})^3$$ 
$\frac{12}{27}$ is from part b
$$\frac{2}{27}+\frac{2}{27}+\frac{2}{27}+\frac{12}{27}+\frac{8}{27}$$
$$\frac{26}{27}$$
alternatively:
$$1-P(0_{heads})$$
$$1-(\frac{1}{3})^3$$
$$\frac{26}{27}$$

Answer (score 0):

For $b,$(if I understood correctly):

You mean what is the possibility of having $2$ heads:

If you need to get exactly $2$ of them, then you need $2$ heads and $1$, the chances of that are $(\frac23)^2 * \frac13 = \frac{4}{27}$. You need to multiply this with $3$ since cases can change.

For having $0$: You need both of them to be tail: $(\frac13)^3 = \frac{1}{27}$

For $c,$:

If you want at least one head, then you can write: What is the possibility that it will never show one head? Then tail has to happen every time, and tail has $\frac13$ chance of happening, and you have get it $3$ times after an other, the probability of that is ($\frac13) ^ 3 = \frac{1}{27}$(you can multiply them, since coin flips are independent events). So the chances of you having at least one head is 1-$\frac{1}{27} = \frac{26}{27}$.